# DynamoDB unique primary key ConditionExpression

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

I am implementing a single table design in dynamodb and overloading keys. My current design allows for an email to be subscribed to a thread.

This is a noSQL workbench screenshot:

[image]

I am using `EM#\<email>` as the partition key and `SB#\<thread id>` as the sort key. I am constructing a putItemCommand from nodeJS lambda env. Basically, the command works as expected.

Here is the payload:

```
new PutItemCommand({
                    TableName: 'sometable',
                    Item: {
                        pk: {
                            S: asEmail(email), //Resolves to `EM${email}`
                        },
                        sk: {
                            S: asSubscription(chain), //Resolves to `SB${chain}`
                        },
                    },
                    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(pk)',
                }),
```

Now I am just confused why this works. I am trying to ensure that the primary key (pk,sk) is unique so an email cannot be subscribed twice to a thread. But I am confused why

```
ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(pk)',
```

correctly accomplishes this. Reading this condition expression makes me believe that it is checking to make sure there is no **partition** key that matches. Is 'pk' an alias or does this have something to do with how dynamo retrieves data? I just need someone to spell this out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [AWS's documentation on condition expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html):

> The following example uses attribute_not_exists() to check whether the primary key exists in the table before attempting the write operation.
>
> > **Note**
> >
> > If your primary key consists of both a partition key(pk) and a sort key(sk), the parameter will check whether `attribute_not_exists(pk)` AND `attribute_not_exists(sk)` evaluate to true or false before attempting the write operation.
>
> ...
>
> ```
> --condition-expression "attribute_not_exists(Id)"
> ```

Note that if your table has a primary key and sort key, then both are required for each item, and they uniquely identify each item. That means that you can't have a duplicate (pk,sk) by definition. If you try to put a new object with the same (pk,sk) as an existing one (without the condition expression), you'll just overwrite the old one.

This counter-intuitive behavior of `attribute_not_exists(pk)` comes from the fact that the (pk,sk) is the item's identifier. Imagine you tried to add an item at (`EM#test2@testing.com`, `SUB#900`) (which doesn't exist). DynamoDB will look up that item and ask, "does it have a pk attribute?" It doesn't (since it doesn't exist), so the put will succeed. If you try to put it a second time, the pk attribute *will* exist, and so the second put will fail.

Another way of looking at this is that since each item must have a pk and an sk, `attribute_not_exists(pk) == attribute_not_exists(sk)` (they either both exist, or neither do), and so checking for one is equivalent for checking for both.

Comment: @BenjaminHobson Happy to help! I added a bit more to explain _why_ this happens (since it is indeed confusing).

Answer (score 1):

Pk is not an alias, it's your partition key name.

As you are doing a put item on a single item, that's where it does the condition check. So you can set your condition either on the PK or the SK and it will work as expected.

Comment: This doesn't fully explain. If 'pk' is the partition key and I have a constraint that the pk should not exist for the put operation to succeed then how can I currently have many entries in my table (first figure) with the same pk (as I currently do as a result of the put operation). Clearly, there is some additional logic I'm missing--and this answer.

Comment: Your condition is only applicable to a single item. That is the item uniquely identified by the primary key. No other items are evaluated.